# Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Even if already enabled

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

Im working on an Android application that includes the Google Maps API. To do that, I enabled this API from [console developers](https://console.developers.google.com)

```
Maps SDK for Android
```

I created a credential, I set a restriction for `App Android` , I added the package of the app and the fingerprint as well and, on the API restriction tab, I selected Maps SDK for Android.
After that, in my application manifest, I wrote the key for google maps. When i build the app from Android studio everything is fine (my phone, one plus 6, is plugged on the pc). The map works as I want. But, if I try to install the generated APK (a signed APK from build -> Generate signed bundle/APK) the map not shows up and i get an error on logcat

```
2018-11-15 10:19:45.590 13249-13249/? I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
2018-11-15 10:19:45.590 13249-13249/? I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
2018-11-15 10:19:45.652 13249-13249/? I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
2018-11-15 10:19:45.655 13249-13249/? I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 14367037
2018-11-15 10:19:45.985 633-13359/? I/netd: ;; res_nquery(maps.googleapis.com, 1, 1)
2018-11-15 10:19:46.162 13249-13358/? W/System.err: com.google.maps.errors.RequestDeniedException: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address *********, with empty referer
2018-11-15 10:19:46.162 13249-13358/? W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.DirectionsApi$Response.getError(DirectionsApi.java:90)
2018-11-15 10:19:46.162 13249-13358/? W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.internal.OkHttpPendingResult.parseResponse(OkHttpPendingResult.java:289)
2018-11-15 10:19:46.162 13249-13358/? W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.internal.OkHttpPendingResult.onResponse(OkHttpPendingResult.java:207)
2018-11-15 10:19:46.250 13249-13356/? E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
2018-11-15 10:19:46.251 13249-13356/? E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): *********;************
```

I can see 2 problems here:

```
This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
```

and

```
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled
```

I really don't understand. Actually, I can't figure it out. I enabled everything and still not working. Is there something else to do?

Answer (score 1):

Its not working as you haven't added SHA of your app's keystore on Google Api Console. You can get your keystore's SHA by using following command in Terminal of Android Studio:-

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

Note: Both name should have full path of file and if you path contains spaces add path in quotes.

Example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\MG\Desktop\My Projects\test.jks" -alias test
```

Answer (score 0):

> API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE

Your API Key is not set in android project !
So  make sure it exists in the AndroidManifest.xml config file first.
Here is my example

```
<application>
....
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="My API key" />
</application>
```

Comment: The OP might have used that as a placeholder to not have their actual key in the post